# How to set DataGridViewColumn data Type at RunTime based on the cell's value?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a Winforms app that has a DataGridView that is databound at runtime. 
One of the columns contains mostly just text but some of it's cells are populated with url's that I would like to make clickable. 
How can I can I tell the DataGridView that if the value in the cell looks like a valid url ie. begins with "http" or something similiar make it a clickable link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution that did the trick was to add the following code to the CellClick event of the DataGridView.

```
if (this.dataGridViewName[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString().StartsWith("http"))
        {
            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.FileName = Utilities.getDefaultBrowser();
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = this.dataGridViewName[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
            p.Start();
        }
```

I got the code to launch the browser  as well as the getDefaultBrowser() code from a very helpful article [here](http://ryanfarley.com/blog/archive/2004/05/16/649.aspx)

Comment: You can skip manually finding the default browser, and let windows use it automatically if just passing the URL, like this: System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(dataGridViewName[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());

Answer (score 1):

[Put a user control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730882(VS.80).aspx) there that has multiple child controls like link, textbox or combobox but only make one of them visible at any time.